# ResponseString from XMLHttpRequest displays in alert but not in div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

So I'm new and trying to display the output of a request as a div using the codes below:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> //button to test requeststring in alert box

<script>
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  xhr.send();
  return xhr;
}

var url = 'http://www.bea.gov/api/data/?&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;

function myFunction() {
    alert(document.getElementById(xhr.responseText);
}
</script>
```

The alert correctly display the responseText when a test button is clicked. However. I cannot display this text in my div using the document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xhr.responseText; line? Any solutions to do the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because AJAX is asynchronous (hence the acronym **A**synchronous **J**avaScript **A**nd **X**ML). The `responseText` property of an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object will not be available immediately, as it creates an addition request to a server that must be completed before you can access the response. You will need to wait for the `readyState` to be `4` using the `onreadystatechange` event listener.

Here's an example of how you could do this by modifying your `createCORSRequest` function to have a callback function that is called when the AJAX request completes.

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> //button to test requeststring in alert box

<script>
function createCORSRequest(method, url, complete){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
          complete(xhr);
      }
  };
  xhr.send();
  return xhr;
}

var url = 'http://www.bea.gov/api/data/?&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
createCORSRequest('GET', url, function(){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
});
</script>
```